# How to give value to a variable passed by parameter inside an if?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scope

I'm trying to give value to a variable passed by parameter inside an if when conditions are met.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SP
@SomeDate DATE
AS
BEGIN

IF @SomeDate IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE_A
    SET DATE1=@SomeDate
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET @SomeDate = GETDATE()
 END

print @SomeDate
-- code that is not actually a print
```

So I want to use @SomeDate after that, but because the value is given in a different scope, it doesn't work how I wanted it to work.
How can I return the value given to @SomeDate (the ELSE part) inside the IF to use it later?

Comment: `It doesn't work how i wanted it to work` How do you want it to work then ? Your variable will be equal to GetDate() when it was null. I dont understand your problem

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the value of @SomeDate back to code outside of the stored procedure? For example to the calling application

Comment: @GuidoG that's true, and that's how I want it to work, I think I did something wrong in the code but did it right writing the question... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you always want to do the update, and use `GetDate()` if the parameter was `NULL`

If that is the case, you can do it more simple like the example below.
If that is not the case, please explain in more detail what you are trying to do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SP @SomeDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
  set nocount on

  if @SomeDate is null
     SET @SomeDate = GETDATE()

  UPDATE TABLE_A
  SET DATE1=@SomeDate

  print @SomeDate
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SP @SomeDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
  set nocount on

  UPDATE TABLE_A
  SET DATE1=ISNULL(@SomeDate,GETDATE())

end
```